# Comparing regexes with recursion

Tags: python, regex, recursion

So I'm stuck here trying to recursively compare regexes with recursion. The user will create an object with two parameters, each a string of length one. These strings can only be `"0"`, `"1"` or `"2"`. But I want to recursively check if these strings point to *another* string as well. Like:

```
  *
 / \
1   2
/    \
2     1
```

I can't figure out how to recursively point to a new object:
This is what I have so far:

```
class DotNode(object):
    def __init__(self, _cargo, _left=None, _right=None):
        self._cargo = _cargo
        self._left = _left
        self._right = _right

    def __eq__(self, _other):
        base = ['0','1','2']
        if self._left in base and self._right in base:
            return self._left == _other._left and self._right == _other._right
        else:
            while self._left not in base or self._right not in base:
                new = self._left
                new2 = self._right
                new3 = _other._left
                new4 = _other._right
                return new._left == new3._left and new2._right == new4._right
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to already know how to do this: recursion. You want to call the `__eq__`function recursively here. I would also advice you check if the given cargo is one of the possible values in the constructor - or even better - every time the value is set.

```
class DotNode(object):
    @property
    def _cargo(self):
         return self._vcargo

    @_cargo.setter
    def _cargo(self, val):
         if val not in ['0', '1', '2']:
             raise ValueError("{} is not a possible value for _cargo.".format(val))
         self._vcargo = val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, DotNode) and self._cargo == other._cargo and self._left == other._left and self._right == other._right
```

## Breaking it down

Of course you want to keep your constructor here. i just wrote the changed parts down. As you may have noticed you don't even need RegExes here, standard string comparison works just fine.

### The `_cargo` property

I changed `_cargo` from a simple attribute to a property here. What does that mean? You get getters and setters à la Java that allow better control over the possible values. The actual data is stored in `_vcargo` of course someone could write to that attribute directly, but that would be downright stupid and you are certainly not responsible if someone uses your code in a way it was not intended. Should you try to set a value different from the possible values, a `ValueError` will be raised.

### The `__eq__` function

As you can see this function is actually very simple. Everything it does is compute whether the cargo of the node itself and the other node is equal. Now, if both subtrees are also equal the whole tree is equal. At the deepest level it will compare `None` with `None` if both trees are equal, because there will be no more subtrees.

Comment: Note that `eq` should probably be able to handle comparisons with non-`DotNode` objects without raising exceptions. Just throw in a `isintance(other, DotNode)` test before checking any of the other attributes of `other`.

Comment: Good point. I was still in C++ mode... Actually, the leaves of the tree might be strings and not nodes themselves, given the current data structure, but I would strongly advice against that.

Comment: @Cu3PO42 Sorry I should haev replied earlier. Yeah the leaves of the tree ARE nodes, this is apart of an exercise for a class. It's confusing because how am I supposed to use a string to point to another object?

Comment: You can't directly use a string to point to another object (at least not in any way that would make the least bit of sense). What you are doing here is just fine and could even be called the "standard" way of building a tree.